# How I can display the image of the selectet variation in the cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Here is my code I want to display the image of each selected variation next to its name in the basket I cannot find the key to the image link of the selected variation Here is my code I want to display the image of each selected variation next to its name in the basket I cannot find the key to the image link of the selected variation Here is my code I want to display the image of each selected variation next to its name in the basket I cannot find the key to the image link of the selected variation

```
<ul class="variation">
    <?php foreach ( $item_data as $data ) : ?>
        <li class="variation-<?php echo sanitize_html_class( $data['key'] ); ?>">
            <span class="item-variation-name"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $data['key'] ); ?>:</span>
            <span class="item-variation-value"><?php echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( $data['display'] ) ); ?></span>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is `$item_data`? How do you get `$item_data`?